# What does this code do in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

Can someone explain me?
please
    ¦  cs:0100   33  D2                   xor    dx,dx
    ¦  cs:0102   B9  10  00               mov    cx,0100)h
    ¦  cs:0105   BE  0F  00               mov    si,00FF)h
    ¦  cs:0108   FD                       std
    ¦  cs:0109  AC                   ARQ: lodsb
    ¦  cs:010A  24  03                    and    al,03)h
    ¦  cs:010C  75  01                    jne    UTN
    ¦  cs:010E  42                        inc    dx
    ¦  cs:010F  E2  F8               UTN: loop   ARQ
    ¦  cs:0111  90                        nop

Comment: For an excellent web reference for Assembly see [**The Art of Assembly Language Programming**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html). While it is primarily written for 8086, all principles are 100% applicable to current assembly programming. The only differences are register sizes, calling conventions and syscall numbers for x86_64. Assembly takes time to learn, you have to digest most of the material before you can expect to begin being fluent writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

Short explanation: basically, it considers an array of 256 bytes starting at address DS:0, and counts the number of bytes containing zero into their two lowest bits. DX contains the result.

Long explanation:
 DX is set to zero (xor dx,dx), CX is the loop counter (0100h = the length of the array to examine), SI is the index in the array, it starts at 00ffh, i.e. the last byte in array. The loop takes in AL the byte pointed by DS:SI (lodsb) and tests if the lowest two bits are zero (and al,03h; jne UTN). If they are zero, DX is incremented. The index SI is automatically decremented by lodsb instruction ("std" instruction selects the autodecrement). The loop is repeated until CX reaches zero (loop ARQ).

Comment: A typo in your answer: **pointed by DS:DX (lodsb)**

Comment: Correct, it's DS:SI, edited